# Ajax request fails in JBOSS EAP 7.1 in Java EAR application

Tags: ajax, java-ee-6, jboss-eap-7

I've EAR applications which run fine in JBOSS EAP 6.3. When I run this application in EAP 7,  then ajax call response is empty after few call. Mainly jsp page calls servlet using ajax. I use common code snippet for AJAX call. I can get response properly first 3/4 times. After that it is not working. The whole thing is working fine in EAP 6.3.

The ajax code snippet is as follows:

```
    try{
                objXMLHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }catch(e){
                try {
                    objXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");     
                }
                catch(e){
                    try {
                        objXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");     
                    }
                    catch(e)    {
                        try {
                            objXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");     
                        }
                        catch(e)    {
                            alert("XMLHTTP Not Supported On Your Browser");
                            return;
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
            var urlstr = "" ;
            var key = "";
            var j = 0;
```

> *//dataStore is an array of key/value pair.*

```
            for(key in dataStore){
                if(j == 0)  {
                    urlstr += key + "=" + dataStore[key];
                    j = 1;
                }   else    {
                    urlstr += "&" + key + "=" + dataStore[key];
                }
            }
            var _dateTime = new Date().getTime();
            urlstr += "&CALLTIME=" + _dateTime + "-";
            var requNumber = "?requNumber=" + _dateTime;
            // http request has been changed as Parameterised
            var _AsyncRequest = true;
            try{
                if(_httpMode == "undefined")
                    _httpMode = "0";
            }catch(e){
                _httpMode = "0";
            }
            if((_httpMode != "undefined") && (_httpMode != null) && (_httpMode == "1"))
            {
                _AsyncRequest = false;
            }
            if(!document.all)
            {
                _AsyncRequest = false;
            }

            if(urlstr.length<=1000) {
                objXMLHTTP.open("POST","XMLDHTTPServlet" + requNumber + "&" + urlstr,false);
            }   else    {
                objXMLHTTP.open("POST","XMLDHTTPServlet" + requNumber,false);   
            }

            urlstr = URLEncode(urlstr); 
            objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") ;
```

> ```
>              //The following is not working after few calls
> ```

```
            if(urlstr.length<=1000) {
                objXMLHTTP.send("");
            }   else    {   
                objXMLHTTP.send(urlstr);
            }  


                rtnXML = objXMLHTTP.responseText;

          if (objXMLHTTP.statusText == "OK" )
```

> *// This condition fails after successive requests*

```
            {
```

> //Code

```
             }
```

> ```
> Following is in JSP page to call the AJAX. Most importantly, when I put the character **|**, then response in empty and objXMLHTTP.statusText shows Bad Request in EAP 7. But EAP 6, it is working fine.
> ```

```
var objXMLApplet = new xmlHTTPValidator();
objXMLApplet.clearMap();
             objXMLApplet.setValue("Package", "panaceaFLweb.getMenuInfo.ReadInfo");
             objXMLApplet.setValue("ValidateToken","true");
             objXMLApplet.setValue("Method", "chkEODStatus");
             objXMLApplet.setValue("BRNCH_CODE",BranCode);
             objXMLApplet.setValue("CURR_BUSS_DATE",CBD);
             objXMLApplet.setValue("DataTypes","S|S");
             objXMLApplet.sendAndReceive();
```

Comment: You said that the backend was changed, but provided only frontend javascript code. Please, share more code.

Comment: Thanks. Code updated

Comment: The main problem is if character | is present in value of any parameter, the Bad Response come in EAP 7 but it is okay in EAP 6. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

It is because character **|** present in URL post request and didn't **encode** the string which length is less than 1000. Just use

> **urlstr = URLEncode(urlstr);**

before **if/else** condition of connection open.

Code snippet are as follows:

```
    urlstr = URLEncode(urlstr);
        if(urlstr.length<=1000) {
            objXMLHTTP.open("POST","XMLDHTTPServlet" + requNumber + "&" + urlstr,false);
        }   else    {
            objXMLHTTP.open("POST","XMLDHTTPServlet" + requNumber,false);   
        }
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") ;
if(urlstr.length<=1000) {
            objXMLHTTP.send("");
        }   else    {   
            objXMLHTTP.send(urlstr);
        }  
rtnXML = objXMLHTTP.responseText;
```

And **URLEncode** function definition are as follows:

```
function URLEncode(urlstr ){
    var SAFECHARS = "0123456789" +  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" +  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + "-_.!~*'()=?&";
    var HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    var plaintext = urlstr;
    var encoded = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < plaintext.length; i++ ) {
        var ch = plaintext.charAt(i);
        if (ch == " "){
            encoded += "+";             
        }else if (SAFECHARS.indexOf(ch) != -1) {
            encoded += ch;
        }else {
            var charCode = ch.charCodeAt(0);
            if (charCode > 255) {
                encoded += "+";
            }else {
                encoded += "%";
                encoded += HEX.charAt((charCode >> 4) & 0xF);
                encoded += HEX.charAt(charCode & 0xF);
            }
        }
    }
    return encoded;
}
```